# Как отсортировать String's с помощью Comparable?

Tags: java, сортировка

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как отсортировать String's с помощью Comparable? Понятно когда работаешь с примитиваvи типа Int. Но как это сделать со стрингами? Спасибо.

Comment: Какой язык вы используете?

Comment: @Ep1demic предполагаю, что Java (:

Answer (score 5):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

// дальше добавляем строки в list 
[...]

// сама сортировка
list.sort((String o1, String o2)->o1.compareTo(o2));
```

Без лямбд:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
```